# Commit major changes in Git

Tags: git, github

I am currently working on a project which I periodically commit to the project Git repository on GitHub. Now I need to make major changes in this project without affecting the current release, so how can I do that in Git?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a branch and commit over there. When you done and your version is stable merge it with your major project.

Also don't forget to commit frequently to avoid big changes to your project.

Answer (score 3):

Create a new branch, then commit to that. see https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-branch.html